# Hi, when i run catkin_make i have an error with nodelet

Tags: ros, catkin-make, build, cmake, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this is result of `catkin_make` :

```
Base path: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1
Source space: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/src
Build space: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/build
Devel space: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/devel
Install space: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/fatima/catkin_ws1/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.16
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - beginner2_tutorials
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner2_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner2_tutorials)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- beginner2_tutorials: 1 messages, 1 services
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:217 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on the catkin package 'nodelet' which must
  therefore be listed as a run dependency in the package.xml
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:98 (_catkin_package)
  beginner2_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:13 (catkin_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/fatima/catkin_ws1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/fatima/catkin_ws1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
fatima@fatima-K55VD:~/catkin_ws1$ ^C
fatima@fatima-K55VD:~/catkin_ws1$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1
Source space: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/src
Build space: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/build
Devel space: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/devel
Install space: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/fatima/catkin_ws1/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.16
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - beginner2_tutorials
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner2_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner2_tutorials)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- beginner2_tutorials: 1 messages, 1 services
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:217 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on the catkin package 'nodelet' which must
  therefore be listed as a run dependency in the package.xml
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:98 (_catkin_package)
  beginner2_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:13 (catkin_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/fatima/catkin_ws1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/fatima/catkin_ws1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

i think as Akif told i should bring it to the package.xml but how? i dont know

its my result when i run catkin_make again :

Base path: /home/fatima/~catkin_ws1
Source space: /home/fatima/~catkin_ws1/src
Build space: /home/fatima/~catkin_ws1/build
Devel space: /home/fatima/~catkin_ws1/devel
Install space: /home/fatima/~catkin_ws1/install
Creating symlink "/home/fatima/~catkin_ws1/src/CMakeLists.txt" pointing to "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake"

##### Running command: "cmake /home/fatima/~catkin_ws1/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/fatima/~catkin_ws1/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/fatima/~catkin_ws1/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/fatima/~catkin_ws1/build"

### -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works

```
Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/fatima/~catkin_ws1/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.6") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/fatima/~catkin_ws1/build/test_results
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.16
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/fatima/~catkin_ws1/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/fatima/~catkin_ws1/build"
####
```

so if it was true `rosrun beginner_tutorials talker` could be run is it true?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222026/hi,-when-i-run-catkin_make-i-have-an-error-with-nodelet/) by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-12-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-12-05**:
We need to see the dependencies section of you package.xml, please.

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-07**:
hi sorry for these days late i have an problem , now i run catkin_make after a few days in root catkin and i receive this result , i edited my last question

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-07**:
i dont know is it true or not?

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-12-08**:
@fatima, did you get any errors when you remove `nodelet` dependency from your `CMakeLists.txt` as @joq suggested?

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-08**:
hi akif, no after a few days when i run `catkin_make` again i hadnt any error without nodelet error i was surprised i edited my answer and put the result above but yet i have the same problem i couldnt run `$ rosrun beginner_tutorials talker` so i dont know is the `catkin_make` run true or not!!!!

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-12-08**:
@fatima, in your question it is written that the package name is `beginner2_tutorials` not `beginner_tutorials` as you try. Can you check it?

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-08**:
yes i did that and my result is :

```
fatima@fatima-K55VD:~/catkin_ws1$ rosrun beginner2_tutorials talker
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named talker below /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/src/beginner2_tutorials
```

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-08**:
i ask new question at [link](http://answers.ros.org/question/222155/rosrun-couldnt-find-executable-named-talker-or-listener/) so thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why did you list `nodelet` as a CATKIN_DEPENDS in your CMakeLists.txt?

The tutorial does not do that. Try removing it.

Maybe you should start over, copying from the tutorial exactly.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1